# Google AppEngine launch the application every 10 minutes

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, yaml, app-engine-flexible

I have a nodejs app deployed on App Engine, the problem i am facing is that the app Engine is hitting command 'node app.js' repeatedly after 10 minutes. I have only one instance of app at a time and currently serving only one version.

Here is the package.json and app.yaml in which app is configured

package.json

```
{
  "name": "appengine-Relay-dashboard",
  "description": "Manages the cronjobs in which the cloud functions are emitted.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy",
    "start":"node app.js",
    "lint": "repo-tools lint",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "system-test": "repo-tools test app",
    "test": "npm run system-test",
    "e2e-test": "repo-tools test deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^1.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.230.1",
    "cron": "^1.3.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.16",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "sleep": "^5.1.1",
    "twilio": "^3.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "2.2.1"
  },
  "cloud-repo-tools": {
    "test": {
      "app": {
        "msg": "Hello, world!"
      }
    },
    "requiresKeyFile": true,
    "requiresProjectId": true
  }
}
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
    instances: 1
resources:
    cpu: 1
    memory_gb: 0.5
    disk_size_gb: 10
```

Here is the problem in the image i am facing

[image: Repeating node.app js command after 10 minutes]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The instance you have running - is it running for more than 10 minutes? Is it possible that it dies or is killed (maybe because it fails health checks)?

Comment: i got the soluton, see my answer below!

Comment: it would be helpful for another in community, if you would describe what you want achieve in code, even if you find solution for yourself already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was the url in the app engine was returning 502 error!
So i made a get request(app.get('/')) to the url and when it started working, it stopped repeating itself.  I got the solution myself.

The main reason was the url was not working at all. So it stopped hitting node app.js once i added the get request to the url and redeployed the app again!